# Question on notation.

Tags: category-theory

I have taken a first course in category theory, I work in a different area. I am trying to read Borceux's chapter "Internal Category theory" in Volume I of Handbook of Categorical Algebra because I need it for a paper. I do not know what the notation e.g $\binom{1_{A_1}}{i\circ d_0}$ means. When is that symbol used and in what context? I have not seen it before. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6):

Borceux uses the column matrix notation for morphisms to products. For instance, $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$ is the unique morphism $T \to X \times Y$ such that $\pi_1 \circ \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = x$ and $\pi_2 \circ \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = y$. Dually, the row matrix notation is for morphisms out of coproducts. And, of course, general matrices denote morphisms from a coproduct to a product in the obvious way.